# Стоит ли ставить тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Я думаю, это плохая идея (?) сближаться с ним.

Answer (score 2):

**Я думаю, это плохая идея ― сближаться с ним.**

Розенталь: При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто  ставится тире. [§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

В данном случае инфинитив поясняет подлежащее *это*. Пояснительный член, выраженный инфинитивом, всегда обособляется не запятой, а тире.

**Сравнить (другие конструкции с инфинитивом):**

Сближаться с ним ― это плохая идея. Тире ставится перед связкой *это*.

Идея сближаться с ним ― плохая. Здесь инфинитив в роли необособленного определения.

*Я думаю* ― вводное предложение.